Why is scipy.stats.rvs_continuous using different arguments than it is passed?
I used scipy.stats.rvs_continuous to make a Phase-Type distribution to model coalescence time. I'll paste the code below, but the gist of the problem is this:
A Phase-Type distribution is defined by a matrix and a vector, so the distribution methods take these as arguments. When I pass these arguments to rvs_continuous, it changes them to be of the same dimension. For example, it coerces a 3x3 matrix, a 3x1 row vector, and a float all to be a 1-D arrays of length 9. While right now I can hard code in reshaping and slicing stuff to make sure functions get the right arguments, it is tedious to do so every time I define a new method.Additionally, while presently I only need this to work for the aforementioned arguments, I would like to define this for the generic case of an nxn matrix, which would just be a bit of a headache like this.
Here is my code
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy import linalg


s1 =np.ones((3,1))


def g_mat(n, p, r):
    c = 1/(2*n*p)
    w = - c - 0.5*r 
    return np.matrix([[w, 0.5*r, 0], [0.5*r,  -1*r, 0.5*r], [0, 0.5*r, w]])
def state_vec(s,g):
    p = (4+3*s)/(4+s)
    p0 = 1/(1+(p**(-1*g/2)))
    return np.array([[p0**2, 2*(1-p0)*p0, (1-p0)**2]])
def ph_cdf(mat, state_vec1, x):
    mat = mat.reshape(3,3)
    return 1 - state_vec1.dot(linalg.expm(x*mat).dot(s1))

def ph_pdf(mat, state_vec1,x):
    mat = mat.reshape(3,3)
    s = -1*mat.dot(s1)
    return state_vec1.dot(linalg.expm(x*mat).dot(s))
def ex_t(mat, state_vec1):
    U =linalg.inv(-1*mat)
    u1= U.dot(s1)
    return state_vec1.dot(u1)[0,0]

class coal_time_dist(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _argcheck(self, mat, vec):
        return (type(mat) == np.ndarray) & (type(vec) == np.ndarray)
    def cdf(self,x, mat, vec):
        x = float(x[0])
        mat=mat.reshape(3,3)
        vec = vec[0:3,]
        return ph_cdf(mat, vec, x)[0]
    def pdf(self,x, mat, vec):
        x = float(x[0])
        mat=mat.reshape(3,3)
        vec = vec[0:3,]
        return ph_pdf(mat, vec, x)[0]
  




Here is what I'm running:
mat = g_mat(1e4, 0.5, 1e-4)
vec = state_vec(0.5, 10)
dist = coal_time_dist(name="dist", badvalue=6)
dist.cdf(10, mat, vec)

Because of the hard coded reshaping, this works, but if I remove that:
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/nzx3cc/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 2120, in cdf
place(output, cond, self._cdf(*goodargs))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<string>", line 38, in _cdf
File "<string>", line 19, in ph_cdf
File "/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_matfuncs.py", line 285, in expm
raise LinAlgError('The input array must be at least two-dimensional')
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: The input array must be at least two-dimensional

And upon printing the shape of the mat parameter, I get (9, 0), even though when I check it outside of the method I get (3,3) as expected. I'm not sure why this is happening, so any help would be appreciated.

Why np.matrix? That's discourged if not actually depricated.  reshape etc with np.matrix behaves different from a ndarray

@hpaulj I originally used ndarray, I  tried casting to matrix to see if it makes a difference for the issue I was seeing, which it doesn't.

Also for unknown, it just changes that matrix into an ndarray regardless, so there isn't a problem with reshape behaving differently.

This needs a [mcf], with just enough code to produce the error.  Only a handful of SO readers have used this stats submodule as you are.  You've probably studied the relevant docs more than most of your readers.  With a easy copy-n-paste we might be more inclined to experiment and offer some insights.

If I call dist.cdf(10, mat, vec) I get an error, int is not subscriptable.  Your first cdf line is float(x[0])!

Your mat is (3,3), vec is (1,3).  So the reshape(3,3) is superfluous.  And the vec[0:3,] doesn't do anything meaningful either.  Looks like your dist.cdf just calls ph_cdf(mat, vec,x) which is purely your own code.

As I read it the (3,3) reshapes do nothing.  vec.dot(linalg.expm(x*mat).dot(s1)) is just a (1,3) dot with a ((3,3) dot with a (3,1)) producing a (1,1). That is for a x=[10]

Have you followed the instructions for inheriting rv_continuous, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html? For starters you should be defining _pdf and _cdf, not pdf and cdf.
